# scikit-learnのErrorメッセージ”cannot import name 'plot_confusion_matrix' from 'sklearn.metrics' の解消方法につき、どなたかご教示ください。

Tags: python, scikit-learn

SVMのregressoarを用いて、金融市場の評価分析を行おうとしています。
テキストを参考にコーディングしたところ、最終行の `plot_confusion_matrix`, `plot_roc_curve` でエラーとなってしまい、先に進めません（メッセージ内容は、タイトル通り）。

エラーメッセージをgoogleで検索し、PIPやsciket-learnのupdateを行い、kernelのRESTARTも掛けたのですが、状況は変わりません。

ちなみに、pipは(22.3.1)、sciket-learnは (1.2.0)です。

どなたかお知恵を授けて頂けないでしょうか？
ちなみに、コーディング内容は下記記載の通りです。

よろしくお願いします。

```
# Base Libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

# Preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, RobustScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, TimeSeriesSplit, GridSearchCV

# SVM
from sklearn.svm import SVR

# Metrics
from sklearn.metrics import  r2_score, mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error, accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, classification_report, confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix, auc, roc_curve, plot_roc_curve**
```

Comment: エラーメッセージは略さずに全てを表示されたままのテキストで提示してください。それからソースコードはimportする部分しか無いようですが、問題の箇所が解決した後でまた別の問題が発生することも考えられるので、一通りのまとまって完結したソースコードを提示してください。あとgoogle-colabとかAnacondaといった何か特徴のある環境ならば、それらの情報も追記してください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ありがとうございました。状況理解しました。

Answer (score 1):

`plot_confusion_matrix`はscikit-learn 1.0.0版で破棄予定(deprecated)になり、1.2.0版で実際に削除された(removed)ようです。
それを使わないように変更するか、使いたいなら1.2.0より前の版にダウングレードしてみてください。1.1.3版以前でしょうか。
[リリース履歴 scikit-learn - PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/#history)

[Version 1.0.0](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v1.0.html#version-1-0-0)
[sklearn.metrics](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v1.0.html#id17)

> - API Change [metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html#sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay) exposes two class methods [from_estimator](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html#sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.from_estimator) and [from_predictions](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html#sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.from_predictions) allowing to create a confusion matrix plot using an estimator or the predictions. `metrics.plot_confusion_matrix` is deprecated in favor of these two class methods and will be removed in 1.2. [#18543](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/18543) by Guillaume Lemaitre.

なお質問のソースから`plot_confusion_matrix`を削除すると今度は`plot_roc_curve`の方で同様にimport出来ないというエラーが発生します。こちらはドキュメントにそうした記述はありませんが、1.2.0版の[API Reference](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html)に名前が載っていない事と、上記記述の後に似た名前の`metrics.plot_det_curve`もdeprecated,removedの記述があるので、ドキュメント化されていないながらも同様に削除されたのではないでしょうか？

---

1.1.3版の[API Reference](https://scikit-learn.org/1.1/modules/classes.html)には記述が残っているようですね。
[Plotting](https://scikit-learn.org/1.1/modules/classes.html#id5)